# What are Servicenow SOAP API getkeys wildcards?

Tags: soap, servicenow

I'd like to use a SOAP request to get a list of items in servicenow table, that have description starting with "TEST".

I am able to send a simple getKeys request. For example the below one is successfully returning to me the sys_id of a single ticket:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:hr="http://www.service-now.com/hr_case">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <hr:getKeys>
         <short_description>TEST Soap 1</short_description>
      </hr:getKeys>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How should I modify the above request, so that it returns keys of all items with  description starting with "TEST"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used instead a REST webservice with the URI:

```
https://???.service-now.com/api/now/table/hr_case?sysparm_query=short_descriptionSTARTSWITHTEST
```

before then I tried a URI like that:

```
https://???.service-now.com/api/now/table/hr_case?&short_description=TEST Soap 1
```